# PHP : Merge 2 csv files using one column as key

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to merge 2 big csv files into one. They both have one common key that can be used to detect lines to be merged.

This is what I tried but this don't work. I always getting only one entry.
Thanks for your help.

```
$handle_modified = fopen($fullpath_modified, 'r');
$handle_standard = fopen($fullpath_standard, 'r');

$jsdatas = [];
$flag1 = true;
while (($csv_standard = fgetcsv($handle_standard, 0, ';')) !== false)
{
    // titles
    if ($flag1)  {
        $titles_standard = $csv_standard;
        $flag1 = false;
        continue;
    }
    $reference_standard = $csv_standard[0];

    $flag2 = true;
    while (($csv_modified = fgetcsv($handle_modified, 0, ';')) !== false)
    {
        // titles
        if ($flag2)  {
            $titles_modified = $csv_modified;
            $flag2 = false;
            continue;
        }

        $reference_modified = $csv_modified[12];

        if ($reference_modified == $reference_standard)
        {
            $jsdatas[$reference_standard] = array_merge($csv_standard, $csv_modified);
            //continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "_always returning error for not enough memory._" Have you tried using `ini_set('memory_limit',-1);` ?

Comment: Are the keys in the input files ordered?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos Yes and the browser hang.

Comment: @Psi In $csv_standart the key is [0] and match the [12] in csv_modified